# Fatal error C1083: Cannot open compiler intermediate file: '***.pch': No such file or directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I have received a project from another. When I built, this error occured. I tried to search Google to solve this problem and I followed [this link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/114334) but no effect.

Comment: So how does you TMP environment variable looks like? Note that there may be too of them (local and global, or I don't remember how windows names them).

Comment: Have you tried rebuild or clean/build...?

Comment: Were you building the entire project, or compiling a particular source file? This error usually occurs when the project is set up to use precompiled headers (PCHs), but the one source file creating PCHs wasn't compiled yet (or setting it up to create PCHs was omitted).

Comment: My TMP environment is %SystemRoot%\TEMP. I have clean and rebuilt many times :(

Answer (score 2):

Try doing Rebuild instead of Build. If this doesn't work, try deleting or renaming the Debug and Release directories, and build again.

Keep in mind that Visual Studio often has 2 sets of Release and Debug directories - one set at the top level directory for the solution, and one at the directory for the project.

Answer (score 2):

This could be due to the length of the path for the intermediate files.

The max path length for visual studio is somewhere around 256 characters.

Whilst considering path lengths don't forget that the compiler may use paths such as `C:\folder1\folder2\folder3\..\..\folder1a\file.obj`, which is longer than you expect for the file `C:\folder1\folder1a\file.obj`.

Inspect your project settings or build output to see what paths are being used, and perhaps try shortening them.

Answer (score 2):

My problem was case sensitive in Windows 10 for partition e:

I have fixed with:

```
fsutil.exe file setCaseSensitiveInfo "e:\" disable
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, and it's because I changed my folder name.
ex: I build the solution when its folder name is 'Folder1' and then I close the entire solution and change my folder name into 'Folder2'. When I re-open the solution, and tried to build it, it has error "Fatal error C1083: Cannot open compiler intermediate file: '***\Folder1***.pch': No such file or directory"

But as satuon said, I tried to rebuild instead of build the solution, it's then working.